# How to Find Local Group Policies in the Windows Registry

Tags: group-policy, automation

I've been able to edit a security setting outlined in [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/04/18/task-scheduler-error-a-specified-logon-session-does-not-exist/) to allow Windows scheduled tasks to run as a user that isn't logged in:

> SECPOL.MSC | Security Settings | Local Policies | Security Options
>
> Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for
>   network authentication = Disabled

but I'd like to be able to script this with what PowerShell offers out of the box. There are PS commands to edit the registry. Is this setting stored in the registry? If it is, how can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [site](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/windows_7/2012-07-02/finding/V-3376) actually listed the path. You can view the setting like this:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" `
                 -Name DisableDomainCreds
```

This will not allow running the scheduled task when the user isn't logged in:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" `
                 -Name DisableDomainCreds -Value 1
```

And this will allow it:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" `
                 -Name DisableDomainCreds -Value 0
```

Hope this helps someone out there.